# Restart a countdown in Livewire with Alpine.js

Tags: countdown, restart, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I try to build a survey, where a countdown should show a modal each 10 seconds, when the user waits too long.
The countdown should be stopped while the modal is shown and it should be restarted when the "back to survey" button is clicked and also when a question is answered.

I tried it that way with the alpine object:

```
let Countdown = () => {
        return {

                open: false,
                heart:'',
                

                ccdown(time,hue) 
                {
                    time -= 1;
                    hue += 60;

                    if (time > 0) {
                    this.heart=setTimeout(this.ccdown, 500, time, hue);
                    console.log("time: "+ time);
                    console.log("hue: " + hue);
                    
                    }
                    if(time == 0) {

                    console.log("done");
                    this.open = true;
                    }
                }

        }    
}
```

This is how I call the function in the blade component:

```
<div x-data="Countdown()" x-init="ccdown(10,30)">
...
</div>
```

But it stops after the second time.
Could anybody show me the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

> setTimeout(this.ccdown, 500, time, hue);

setTimeout only accepts two arguments, the function, and the timeout. If you have to call the function using arguments, you should either use bind or create a new function. So either it should be:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.ccdown(time, hue)
}, 500)
```

Or,

```
setTimeout(this.ccdown.bind(this, time, hue), 500)
```